# How to know which input files are shared between two C programs?

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor

When I execute two C Programs in Linux, I can print their local/private file descriptor by using `fileno()`. It means, when I run two independent programs side by side, and  print `fileno()` in each of them, 3 is printed for the first file opened, 4 is printed for the second file opened and so on.

Therefore, by using `fileno()`, it is not possible to know which input files are shared between them.

Is there any way to print the input file name that is shared between two C programs?

Comment: In general, you can't readily tell.  Each program knows which files it works with, but neither knows the files that the other works with.  Do you need a supervisory program that runs the two programs and keeps track of things?  Which program needs to know?  Why does either program need to know?  And the file descriptor numbers won't tell you a thing — not on their own.  You might get useful information from `fstat()` on a file descriptor, but comparing numbers alone won't tell you anything.

Comment: You can probably figure it out with `lsof` and a quick Perl or awk script.

Comment: `strace` can also show you every file that is opened by each process, as it happens.  But it cannot be done after the process has started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
readlink /proc/<pid>/fd/* | sort -u > /tmp/process-<pid>.out
```

to create a file with a list of all files opened by a process with PID `<pid>`.
then use `comm`(1) to find the common files, as follows:

```
comm -12 /tmp/process-<pid1>.out /tmp/process-<pid2>.out
```

Note that this will list *all* files shared by these programs.

if you know that the specific file descriptors used by the program are e.g. 3,4,5,9,11,12, then replace the first command with:

```
readlink /proc/<pid>/fd/{3,4,5,9,11,12} | sort -u > /tmp/process-<pid>.out
```

If you don't know the file descriptors, and you want to assume that all the file descriptors which are open for read (including stdin) are input files, you'll have to do something more clever by reading `/proc/<pid>/fdinfo/<file-descriptor>`, which prints a `flags` field, which has that information.

Comment: I believe the `Linux` tag above qualifies which OS the `c` programs are running on. You may be right, therefore no ding, but I suspect he is looking for a `c` solution and not  POSIX shell solution. (**note:** `fileno` is a POSIX extension provided by `stdio.h` with gcc)

Comment: Doesn't that assume that a name uniquely identifies a file? Because that's not true on Linux.

Comment: @melpomene Linux remembers the hard-link through which the file was opened. If, however, the file was moved after being opened, that wouldn't work.